# Setting context-path J2EE compiled by netbeans

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans-8, glassfish-4.1, contextroot

i developed an application for university, but for some reasons seems to be impossible for me to set the context-root of it. This is what i tried to do:

- Changing context-root from glassfish-web.xml but it's not working. The server recognize ever /web/ path (the name of web module). This is my XML

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
  <glassfish-web-app error-url="">
     <web-uri>web</web-uri>
     <context-root>/</context-root>
     <class-loader delegate="true"/>
     <jsp-config>
        <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
         <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
        </property>
     </jsp-config>
  </glassfish-web-app>
  ```
- I tried to set context-root from asadmin using deploydir. It deploy the app but it run it always to /web/ path.
- I tried to check domains.xml, but i have not others apps and my app hasn't a context-root set as a property.
- The only strange thing that i see in server logs are this:

  ```
  SEVERE:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/Danilo/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ibei/dist/gfdeploy/ibei/
  WARNING:   Unsupported deployment descriptors element web-uri value web.
  WARNING:   Context path from ServletContext: /web differs from path from bundle: web
  ```

The last warning is really strange, cause the web app is called simply "web". I tried to make web-uri web, web.war, web_ear but it never recognize the web-uri as correct :(

Comment: <web-uri>web</web-uri> remove this.

Comment: @maress this solved the warning, but still the application is running in the folder "/web/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution, thx to JBoss doc that are better then glassfish and netbeans togheter. The problem is caused by the presence of an APP composed by two modules:
 - EJB
 - WEB

That two modules are contained in an ear that, cause of netbeans, has no "application.xml" so glassfish simply doesn't look at "glassfish-web.xml" and using asadmin can't work too. The only solution is to add the application.xml like this (in the "configuration files" folder of the project):

```
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" version="1.4"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com /xml/ns/j2ee 
                         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/application_1_4.xsd">
  <display-name>Ibei</display-name>

  <module>
    <ejb>ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>web.war</web-uri>
        <context-root></context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

Comment: <!-- fix for 
             WARNING: Context path from ServletContext: /test differs from path from bundle: test --> <web-uri>test.war</web-uri>
 <context-root>/test</context-root>